# Scrolling in nested columns in Bootstrap 5

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I created a basic layout for a one page application in REACT by using Bootstrap v5.
The application consists of two columns and nested rows in it. I expand the columns to the max height of the screen. I do not want to have the main scrollbar of the browser but inside the nested columns.

My basics layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vh-100" style="background-color:aquamarine;">
    <div class="col-md-8 border d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row border">
        <h1 class="display-4">Headline</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row border flex-grow-1" style="background-color:blue;">
        Box 1
      </div>
      <div class="row border" style="background-color:red;">
        Box 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 border">
      Box3
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Box 1 is expanded that the complete height is used. If I am importing a REACT component to this box which is higher as the box in the viewport a scrollbar should appear. Is this possible? How?

I can add a scrollbar by `className="overflow-scroll"` inside the REACT component I want to include but than the flex-height of the column is ignored, too.

Thanks in advance!
nico

Comment: I think you need to set the `max-height` property as well as the `overflow-y: scroll;`. Max-height caps the height at a set value so other values will have to be scrolled as overflow, does this help?

Comment: If I set the `max-height` property in the REACT component to px it is working, that i can scroll in the component. But than the box is not expanded anymore. Setting it to 100% is also not working. The component ignores the `flex-grow-1` property.

Comment: what happens if you set overflow y in react as well?

Comment: Finally I found a solution for the problem. I think it is not the most elegant way but for the first vision it works:
I am reading the size of the visible div-container and using this for rerender the content inside (a PDF). For the first render I hardcoded numbers.
Combined with your tip ``max-height`` it is working as expected. Now I have to test on different system.

Comment: Have you tried adding some like a `max-height: calc(100vh - ...px);` to Box 1 where the `...` represent the otehr content on your page like your navbar height so it uses 100% of your viewport height and then subtracts the remaining pixels that are used so the max height of Box 1 is what you want it to be, idk if this solves your problem but this would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hey! Great tip! This makes it more flexible to control the height of the showed PDF in the responsive design after breaking down to to smaller screens.

Comment: Nice man glad to help, getting something to work on every viewport keeps being a challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution for me:

```
<div className="row p-3 overflow-auto flex-grow-1">
  <div style={{"maxHeight": "calc(100vh - 450px"}}>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The content is a PDF, rendered by the react-pdf package.